# RegEx select all between two character

Tags: regex

Example:
I want to extract everything between "Item:" until " * "

`Item: *Sofa (1 SET), 2 × Mattress, 3 × Baby Mattress, 5
Seaters Car (Fabric)*
Total price: 100.00
Subtotal: 989.00`

But I only managed to extract `"Item: *"` and `" Seaters Car (Fabric)* "` by using `(.*?)\*`

Comment: `Item: .+\*` if the first word is literally `Item`

Answer (score 0):

After matching `Item:`, match anything but a colon with `[^:]+`, and then lookahead for a newline, ensuring that the match ends at the end of a line just before another label (like `Total price:`) starts:

[`Item: ([^:]+)(?=\n)`](https://regex101.com/r/zj7YVQ/1)

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)